# View getRootView returns itself

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a made a custom Button called ActionButton and I'm trying to get reference to another view that is in a parallel view hierarchy. I thought of using `findViewById(int id)`, but I kept getting `NullPointerExceptions`, so I tried to get reference to the RootView via `getRootView()`, and from there get the view with `findViewById(int id)`. The problem is now that `getRootView` instead of returning a layout or null, it returns my ActionButton that called that method.

Here is my ActionButton, where I try to get reference:

```
public class ActionButton extends Button {

    protected void onFinishInflate(){
        super.onFinishInflate();
        log(getRootView() == this)    //true, what I don't understand...
        ConnectionLayer connectionLayer = (ConnectionLayer) findViewById(R.id.connection_layer);  //Returns null...
    }
}
```

And a overview of my layout.xml file:

```
<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

      (much more xml elements)

      <com.cae.design.reaction.ui.ActionButton
            android:id="@+id/actionButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <com.cae.design.reaction.ui.ConnectionLayer
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/connection_layer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   </com.cae.design.reaction.ui.ConnectionLayer>

</FrameLayout>
```

I would really appreciate if you could explain to me why `getRootView` returns the view itself or could give me a hint how I can reference it any other way.

Answer (score 2):

If you'll take a look at the source code of the getRootView method:

```
 public View getRootView() {
        if (mAttachInfo != null) {
            final View v = mAttachInfo.mRootView;
            if (v != null) {
                return v;
            }
        }

        View parent = this;

        while (parent.mParent != null && parent.mParent instanceof View) {
            parent = (View) parent.mParent;
        }

        return parent;
    }
```

you'll see, that the only case when this method returns itself is the case if the view has not been attached to the view hierarchy (and mAttachInfo.mRootView is not null) and it has no parent or a parent is not a View instance.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [getParent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29) instead, and cast the result to `ViewGroup` if needed. Then, you can access the other child views using `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()`.

Comment: No, this also doesn't work. when i call `getParent` it returns null, so it looks like the problem is that my ActionButton isn't added to the view hierarchy. But I thought when the method `onFinishInflate` gets called, the layout would be finished...

Comment: Hmm, might need to do you logic in a later call, like `onPreDraw` or `onAttatchedToWindow` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

getRootView() returns itself because at the time when ActionButton finishes iflating it's parent doesn't. I mean that ActionButton doesn't connected to LinearLayout whe you call getRootView(). I do this when I need a root view:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
                    // wait until LinearLayout will finish inflating and this
                    // view will be connected to it
        while(getRootView() == this) {} 
        // do your buisness now
    }
}).start();
```